# Simplifying an expression failed

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression(complex), which I need to simplify. I kept it for more than 1 day. But after that I just received all the expression with faint blue(how they appears on first time opening the Mathematica). However, just to increase the troubles more, there was no output. Moreover, this is not first time with the same expression or program, it has happened every time. I needed to simplify the expression, in order to do an integration, later. Either I can do the integration without simplification or simplification then integration. In any case, there was no answer but only the faint blue screen. I have no idea, what is going on!!

[Long Expression](https://pastebin.com/2Bjgmi4v)

Comment: If your variables turn blue, that means your kernel died.

Comment: @Bill I mean full simplify. It is really surprising. Let me check out now.

Comment: @Bill Why leafcount? I just need to simplify the expression. It is 2X2 Matrix. There has to be a simplified matrix

Comment: @CarlWoll Excatly that what happened. Is there a way to keep the code running without killing the kernel. Thanks

Comment: @Bill I am confused. You mean to say that, you have simplified only a single component in 8 sec. expr[[1,2]]?

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. I have shown you exactly the code I evaluated. It is presented in grey text. `Timing[Simplify[expr]]` 13 seconds. `Timing[Simplify[expr[[1, 2]]]]` 2.6 seconds. Why four hours ago `Timing[{LeafCount[expr], LeafCount[Simplify[expr]]}]` was 7.8 seconds and now it is 13.4 I don't know. Next `FullSimplify` is a completely different function that takes orders of magnitude more time than `Simplify`. `Timing[FullSimplify[expr]]` I don't know, maybe a month or a century IF I had a terabyte of memory, I can't guess that time. Please duplicate every step I have done.